# How do I grab the left 3 Characters of a listitem

Tags: regex, forms, parsing, coldfusion, listitem

I am working in ColdFusion. Here is the issue I am having. I have a form with a number of fields in it, including checkboxes. The checkboxes follow a standard naming convention, for instance every check box is named "chk" then the name. So EMT would be named chkEMT, and so on. I am looping through the form.fieldnames and I need to get all the form fields beginning with "chk", then remove the "chk" from the fieldname and return just the remainder of the name, such as "EMT". So "chkEMT" is parsed and returned as "EMT" the rest of the fieldnames can be skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfset testList = "chkOne,chkTwo,chkThree,zzzNothing,chkFour" />
<cfloop list="#testList#" index="i" >
    <cfif left(i,3) eq "chk">
        <cfoutput>#right(i,len(i)-3)#</cfoutput>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, that worked perfectly! I appreciate everyones answers, I learn something new from every one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chk(\w+)`
Which captures strings starting with `str` and continuing with a word (words/numbers/undersocre)

This will capture the rest of the word within the capturing parentheses. You access the captured portion using the relevant regex API you use.